# Streaming a dynamic zip from Amazon S3

Tags: ruby, actionscript, zip, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am looking for a way to dynamically stream download a zip of files from Amazon S3.

The application is hosted on EC2 and the files are stored on S3.

Need to give users the ability to select from a group of files which will then get bundled up and downloaded to them.

Have heard about a few Actionscript libraries (aszip and fzip) that might be possible, or could do this in Ruby, or even possibly PHP.

The files do not need any compression, zip is just being used to bundle the files up into one single download....

Comment: I'd like to see a solution for this that does *not* involve using the web server as a proxy between amazon s3 and the client.

Comment: https://github.com/gchaincl/s3zipper

Answer (score 3):

I use [Nginx Zip Module](http://wiki.nginx.org/NgxZip) to stream local files, but there is option to stream from remote locations. Otherwise you could use it with VFS mounted S3 storage as local filesystem.
It supports seek - resumable and accelerated downloads

Comment: That sounds interesting, Gertas, thanks for the tip. I will look into this. We did end up using a Flash solution, but are currently in the process of redoing our system, so this could come in handy.

Comment: Zip module for nginx supports zip64 which means archives can contain files >2GB, it works very well. I suppose flash download has some drawbacks - needs user click to save, can't create links to zip files and up to 100MB is officialy supported.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use Mono, [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com) will do it.

```
Response.Clear();
Response.BufferOutput= false;  // necessary for chunked output
String ReadmeText= "This content goes into an entry in the " +
                   "zip file.  Timestamp, MD5, whatever." ; 
string archiveName= String.Format("archive-{0}.zip", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MMM-dd-HHmmss")); 
Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "filename=" + archiveName);

using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
{
    zip.AddEntry("Readme.txt", "", ReadmeText, Encoding.Default);
    zip.AddFiles(filesToInclude, "files");
    zip.Save(Response.OutputStream);
}
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

DotNetZip is open source, free to use.

Answer (score 0):

Java supports streaming zips too. take a look at the java.utils.zip package. i used that to implement a pipline consisting of FTP, UNZIP, XSLT, CSV units. it works like a charm.

Martin